# closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\ln(2k+1+n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, closed-form

In my work on another problem I arrived at this sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\ln(2k+1+n)$$

It appears to converge for practically any $n$.  Is this a known sum that I can find references to? Does it have a closed form?  Should I try converting the log into a series?

Comment: I have only solution for `n=-2`: $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \ln (2 k-1)}{2 k-1}=-\frac{1}{4} \pi  \ln
   (4)-\frac{\gamma _1\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{4}+\frac{\gamma
   _1\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{4}$ where: $\gamma _1\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ is  generalized Stieltjes constant.

Comment: Deploring the premature closing of an interesting question I squeeze down my exended comment to this formula for the sum $s_m = \int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{e^{-m t} \operatorname{arctan}\left(e^{-t}\right)}{t}-\frac{\pi  e^{-t}}{4 t}\right) \, dt$, here $m=n-2$. The dependence on $m$ is nicely isolated here. Hoping for reopening the question to allow me to elaborate more.

Comment: An equivalent formula ($e^{-t}\to s$) is $s_m=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\log(s)} \left(\frac{\pi }{4}-s^m \frac{\operatorname{arctan}(s)}{s}\right) \, ds$.

Comment: Embracing all $m$: for the generating function with respect to $m$ we obtain $g(z) = \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } s_{m} z^m = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\log(s)} \left(\frac{\pi }{4 (1-z)}-\frac{\operatorname{arctan}(s)}{s (1-s z)}\right)\, ds$, i.e. a single integral.

Comment: Excellent! That's much nicer than what I found.

Answer (score 3):

By the alternating series test, it converges for all $n>-3$ (and in fact for all $n\in \mathbb{C}$ such that all the terms of the series exist). A closed form is known for $n=-2$:$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1} \log(2k-1) =\beta'(1)= \frac\pi4(\gamma - \log \pi) + \pi \log\Gamma(3/4)
$$ 
according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

I don't expect there's a nice closed form for any other special value of the sum. Let $f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\log(2k-1+z)$; then your sum is $f(n+2)$ (it's slightly nicer to shift the argument). The closest thing to a closed form I could find for $f$ is it's Taylor series $$
f(z) = \beta'(1) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\beta(n+1)}{n} (-z)^n
$$
where $\beta$ is the [Dirichlet Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function). To prove this, recall $\log(a + z) = \log(a) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n a^n}(-z)^n$. Applying this to $f$:\begin{eqnarray}
f(z) &=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\log(2k-1+z)\\ &=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\log(2k-1) - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2k-1)^n} (-z)^n\\ &=& -\beta'(1) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\beta(n+1)}{n}(-z)^n
\end{eqnarray}
Also closed form adjacent is $$
f'(z) = -\frac{\pi}{4z} - \frac{1}{4z}\left(\psi\left(\frac{z+1}4\right) - \psi\left(\frac{z+3}4\right)\right)
$$
where $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). Proof:\begin{eqnarray}
f'(z) &=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-1)(2k-1+z)}\\ &=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\frac1{z(2k-1)} - \frac1{z(2k-1+z)} \right) \\
&=& \frac1z\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1} - \frac1z\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k-1+z} \\
&=& -\frac{\pi}{4z}- \frac{1}{4z}\left(\psi\left(\frac{z+1}4\right) - \psi\left(\frac{z+3}4\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}
see [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20k%3D1%20to%20infinity%20%28-1%29%5Ek%2F%282k-1%20%2B%20z%29) for the last step.

Answer (score 2):

**This isn't an answer**, but a possible numerical strategy.

Given the following numerical series:

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\,\frac{\ln(2\,k + 1 + n)}{2\,k - 1}
$$

with $n > -3$ fixed, being a series with alternate sign terms, it can be calculated numerically using an efficient [algorithm](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/exp-math-9/fulltext.pdf): *the method of Henri Cohen, Fernando Rodriguez Villegas and Don Zagier*.

In particular, for $n = 17$, writing in *Wolfram Mathematica 12.0*:

```
CVZ[fct_, {var_, varmin_}, niter_] :=
    Module[{a, b, c, d, n},
            a = ((3 + Sqrt[8])^niter + (3 - Sqrt[8])^niter) / 2;
            b = -1;
            c = -a;
            d = 0;
            Table[c = b - c;
                  d = d + c fct (-1)^varmin /. {var -> n + varmin};
                  b = (n + niter) (n - niter) b / ((n + 1/2) (n + 1)),
                 {n, 0, niter - 1}];
            N[{d/a, Abs[d/a^2]}]
          ];

CVZ[Log[2 k + 1 + 17] / (2 k - 1), {k, 1}, 8]
```

you get immediately:

> {-2.33885, 3.51254*10^-6}

which are the sum and the respective maximum error made with only $8$ iterations.

Also, through this other simple code:

```
data = Table[CVZ[Log[2 k + 1 + n] / (2 k - 1), {k, 1}, 8], {n, -2, 1000}];

ListPlot[data[[All, 1]], PlotRange -> All]

ListPlot[data[[All, 2]], PlotRange -> All]
```

you get immediately:

[image]

where the $8$ iterations remained fixed; by increasing the number of iterations the maximum errors committed will decrease, while the calculation times will increase.